# Twitching camera image during movement. In Unity 2D

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm trying to make simple 2D runner.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate (SP1), Unity 5.3.2 (also tested with 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.2.4).

I've caused a bug which is visible in editor, standalone builds, Android builds.

I've created new project in 2D. And put a movement script to a camera:

```
private float m_speed = 0;
void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(m_speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0) //RIGHT
    {
        m_speed = 5f;
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0) //LEFT
    {
        m_speed = -5f;
    }
    else //STOP
    {
        m_speed = 0f; 
    }
}
```

I've added to a sceene simple cube in front of camera.
As a result (in Play mode), when i'm moving camera (it moves with stable speed) - image (cube) is twitching.
In quality setting of a project - changes in V Sync Count `Don't Sync` and `Every V Blank` doesn't make any visible sence, but `Every Second V Blank` increases twitching.

I've tried to add rigidbodies and use Interpolate settings, like in a similar problem at [forum (with video)](http://www.unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5713&st=0&sk=t&sd=a)

didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hey Dmitriy - I really think you will have to upload the project and have a link to it (use one of the free sites where you can host a zip file).  I'll have a look at it if you post it.  (Just deleted any private info if you like.)  PS please dont forget with Unity you ONLY INCLUDE the Assets/ and ProjectSettings/ folders, when zipping or using source control.  Cheers!

Comment: note, VSync etc is totally unrelated, you can be sure  :O

Comment: @JoeBlow , I've found disscusion topic at [unity3d.forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/gfx-waitforpresent.211166/), and 202 posts made twitching almost imperceptible, but in builds for Andriod device the twitching exists.

Comment: Understood -- sorry I am unable to help in any way!  I would be interested to download your project if you get a chance.  We make Android apps.

Comment: Copy/paste answer from unity3d.ru - StackOverflow community needs to know this :)

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using transform.poisition instead of transform.translate it should give smoother movement afaik

Comment: Thnaks, but `transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + m_speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);` didn't solve a problem